# Laravel Socialite Facebook Wrong redirects, giving parameter app_id is required

Tags: laravel, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5, facebook-login, laravel-socialite

I am using Laravel 5.2 in which I have configured Socialite 2.* for using facebook login. It was working few days ago, but suddenly it has start giving "The Parameter app_id is required". I have placed my credentials in config.services.php file as stated in the documentations. But nothing's working.

Comment: Please provide a piece of code in order to grasp the whole problem, and do you face this problem on local & production?

Comment: Please show the configuration (just replace the sensitive details with * or something like that) so users can see what might be wrong with it. Maybe copy & paste the actual error message and/or stack trace to help us debug the issue with you.

Comment: This is my redirect function written in my controller file -
public function redirect(){
       return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();  
}

This is fb credentials written in my config/services.php file.

'facebook' => [
        'client_id' => '12500343482****',
        'client_secret' => '92448565c13a41d94393deb68451****',
        'redirect' => 'my_redirect_url',
    ],

Comment: I do have provided the app_id in the services.php file, don't know why it is still giving this error. And also my url is generating differently now in the browser

Comment: I just get this error when Im trying to login with FB -- > "The parameter app_id is required"